# How to use fractions in C?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am learning C now in DevC++ and I need to solve a simple exercise where a number (int or float, which is 10 in this case) is multiplied by a rate, which is a fraction (1/6 in this case). The output I get is 0.000000 when I run my code below, which is not correct. This works correctly on some fractions, such as 4/2.

What am I doing wrong? **Please note: I cannot use some advanced solutions and functions because we haven't studied those. Also I have to use constants as part of the exercise because the fraction is already known at the start of the exercise.** My code needs to be as simple as the one I am using now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const float a = 10;
const float b = 1/6;
float c;

main()
{
   
   c = a * b;

   printf("Answer = %f", c);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`const float b = 1/6;`

`1/6` is the integer division and it is equal `0`

You need to use float constants:

`const float b = 1.0f/6.0f;`

The constants with suffix `f` have `float` type (`1.0f`, `5.12f`). Without the suffix have `double` type (`1.0`, `5.12`)

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to use () for the fraction so that it does that calculation first? For example `const float b = (1.0/6.0)`

Or does the division take precedence automatically?

Comment: only if you neet to set the order of evaluation for example `(1.0 +5.0)/2.0`

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The constants `1` and `6` are both integers, so `1/6` performs integer division.  If you want floating point division one or both values should be floating point constants:

```
const float b = 1.0/6.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You perform division on two constant integers, which are `1` and `6`, and the result of such operation is equal to `0` and that value is being passed to `float`. Change the value of `b` to `const float b = 1.0 / 6.0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use floating point numbers, like `1.0` (and not `1`, which happens to be integer) or `6.0` (and not `6`, which is also an integer)

When you apply the division operator `/` to two integers, it does *integer division* which means the result should be an integer.

If you divide the integer `1` by `6`, you get `0`, and a remainder of `1`.

The best you can do is using floating point literals when you want floating point expressions, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const float a = 10.0;    /* this time everything is double */
const float b = 1.0/6.0; /* you convert it into float on initialization */
float c;

main()
{
   
   c = a * b;            /* ... or when assigning */

   printf("Answer = %f", c);

   return 0;
}
```

and your program will work fine.